# Front end fails to decode ASP.NET Core server response. TypeError: Decoding failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

Recently I had a weird issue where I had a POST endpoint in my ASP.NET Core 7 server.
This POST endpoint, when called by our front end application (NexrJS with a proxy calling our server), was returning the following error:

`TypeError: Decoding failed`

Does this error mean the client cannot decode/understand the backend response?

For some reason, once I changed my endpoint POST response from

```
Ok(response);
```

to

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(SignUp), response, response);
```

it stopped failing. Also, note that when the response was failing, there was a `Content-Encoding=gzip` header

Where is this header coming from? And why once I changed my response, it stopped sending the Content-Encoding header, and the call was successful?

I'm hosting this server in Azure Web App service and the version is ASP.NET Core 7.

**UPDATE**

I'm experiencing now the same problem with a GET endpoint that was returning as follows:

`Ok(products)`

However, changing this to just `return products` is not making the error to go away. Nor the gzip header which I think it's the one causing problems

Comment: `TypeError` is a JavaScript error message - it's not something ASP.NET would ever generate by itself. Are you behind an `nginx` proxy? You say you're on Azure App Service, but are you on a Windows or Linux AppServicePlan? When you say "front-end" are you referring to a JavaScript SPA client - or the Azure AppService front-end load-balancers - or do you mean your ASP.NET Core code itself is a front for another layer of back-end services?

Comment: @Dai - right, so my frontend is a NextJS application. It has a proxy who is in charge of calling the server endpoints in Azure (Windows App Service). Let me know if this provides more context. Really trying to figure this out

Comment: @Dai, I think the Content-Encoding gzip header is causing the problem. Do you know where this is coming from? And as I explained, why changing the response removed the header? How can I make sure every endpoint does not add that header

Comment: Does you controller have a `[Produces("application/json")]` attribute to control encoding of responses?

Comment: It dosen't have it. I'm Trying `[Produces("application/json")]`. Will know shortly

Comment: Didn't work. Not sure how to solve this or why is this even happening

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:  Actually, I don't think this answers the original question.***

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult CreatedAtAction (string? actionName, object? routeValues, object? value)`

You are passing a response where a route value is required.

The route value should have parameters that match the route properties of the action.

e.g. if the action is

```
[Route("/account/user/{id}")]
```

Then your routeValues object should include an id property (probably with matching case, if your controllers are configured so).

Personally, I would make it more obvious:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(SignUp), new {id=response.Id}, response);
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! But yeah, it doesn't really answer my question